# Sql 2000 Connect From Domain PC to WorkGroup PC using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server

Sql 2000 -

I am trying to connect from a PC w/ client tools that is on a domain, to a Sql Server 2000 box that is NOT on the domain using Windows Authentication. I thought I had done this in the past this by creating an account on the non domain PC with the same username/pwd I am logged in on the domain PC, but that doesn't seem to be working.

I am specifically looking at using Windows Authentication, I know Sql Authentication works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log in with a Windows account local to the SQL 2000 box, you need to make sure that account has permissions to log in.  By default, the BUILTIN\Administrators group has full access to SQL, so if you add the account you've created to that, you should be good to go (obviously, you could configure it differently to provide more granualar access).

There doesn't need to be any relation between your domain account and the local account on that PC, just use those local credentials when you log in through the client tools.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I can log in locally the Sql Server. The issue is when I try to log in using windows authentication from a PC on a domain to the Sql Server which is not part of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Have encountered a similar problem. Windows SQL authentication always takes the credentials of the currently logged in user. There's no 'run as' type method to get around this, as far as I'm aware.

So your problem basically boils down to needing some common ground on where both your server can log on, and your remote SQL box can authenticate, using the same username/password. Since they're not on a common logon domain or have any kind of trust, you may be stuck here.

Back when I ran into this issue we worked around it by using SQL authentication. One dev at the time did find another way around in the code itself by changing method/library by which the app connected.